# Disable specific dates for a specific input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable some array dates for a specific input field for a datepicker calendar. But those dates are not disabled in the calendar for that specific input field.

**html**

```
 <input class="form-control time_slot_searchField" id="datepicker" name="" type="text"  required="" style="">
<input class="form-control" id="patient_email" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="patient_email">
<input class="form-control" id="patient_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="patient_name">
```

**script**

```
var exclude = ["2019-06-14","2019-06-15","2019-06-16"]

                $('input').datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function(date){
                        var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [ exclude.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
                    }
                });
```

this date disables script apply in all the input field.

But I want to apply the script only for id `#datepicker` input field.

That's why I used 
`$('input #datepicker').datepicker` instead of `$('input').datepicker`

But doesn't work.

How to apply disable dates only that id `datepicker` input field.

Anybody help, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not correct. You should not have space between the "input" and "#datepicker". It should be like

```
$('input#datepicker').datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function(date){
                        var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [ exclude.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
{
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var day = d.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 3)];
    }
});
```

});

Here before show date function will restrict the specific date.

Comment: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> Try to add this in html

Answer (score 0):

solved....!!!

replace the below part

```
$('input').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                    var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                    return [ exclude.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
                }
            });
```

with this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date){
                        var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [ msg.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
                    });
```